# jQuery function of $(selector) not updating the website/page

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have the following jQuery code:

```
function preprocess(form) {
    $(form).find(".input input").each(function() {
        var required = $(this).attr("required");
        var checkField = $(this).closest("tr").children(".check");
        var errorField = $(this).closest("tr").children(".errormessage");
        if (required != undefined) {
            $(checkField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $(checkField).html("&#x2718;");
            $(errorField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $(errorField).html("(Required)");
        }
        else {
            $(checkField).css("color", "#FFFF00");
            $(checkField).html("&#x2714;");
            $(errorField).css("color", "#000000");
            $(errorField).html("");
        }
    });
}
```

On a direct load of the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form").each(function() {
        preprocess($(this));
    });
});
```

This works fine, as expected.

Then it can also come through an AJAX load:

```
function loadPage(dataUrl) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "content/" + dataUrl + ".php",
        success: function(html) {
            setContent(html, dataUrl);
        },
        error: function(html, message) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "content/notfound.php",
                success: function(html) {
                    setContent(html, "notfound");
                },
                error: function(html, message) {
                    finalError(message);
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function setContent(html, url) {
    $(".middle .container .text").html(html);
    $(html).filter("form").each(function() {
        console.log($(this));
        preprocess($(this));
    });
    //only if you actually load a different page
    if (getCurrentFilename() != url) {
        window.history.pushState({
            "url": url
        }, "", url);
    }
}
```

Here it does not work.

I have debugged it and the `preprocess(form) { /* ... */ }` works as expected. However the 'updates' (`.css()`, `.html()`) do not work when it is being loaded dynamically.

Anyone has any clue? I think it is kind of hard to make a JFiddle if I'm using AJAX though...

**EDIT:** Literal content received from AJAX request (outputting it to the console, I added `console.log(html)` at the top of `setContent(html, url) { /* ... */ }`):

```
<h2>Register</h2><br>
<p>Please use different email and password than the ones you use for your Warframe account.<br>We do our utmost best to protect your account details, but everything can be hacked.</p><br>
<form name="register" method="post" data-rules="register" data-service="register" data-onsuccess="register_success">
<table class="accdet">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">E-mail:</td>
        <td class="input"><input type="email" name="email" required></td>
        <td class="check"></td>
        <td class="errormessage"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Warframe ingame name:</td>
        <td class="input"><input type="text" name="ingame" required></td>
        <td class="check"></td>
        <td class="errormessage"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Password:</td>
        <td class="input"><input type="password" name="password" required></td>
        <td class="check"></td>
        <td class="errormessage"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Password confirmation:</td>
        <td class="input"><input type="password" name="passwordcheck" required></td>
        <td class="check"></td>
        <td class="errormessage"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">Kiosk available?</td>
        <td class="input"><input type="checkbox" name="kiosk"></td>
        <td class="check"></td>
        <td class="errormessage"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" class="submit">
</form>
```

I'll try and see if JFiddle in combination with AJAX is possible.

Comment: what give you: `checkField .length`  ??? If 0, you know where is your issue

Comment: `checkField .length = 1`, as expected.

Comment: What is the content received back from the ajax request?

Comment: @RichardDalton Added per request

Comment: I continued debugging it and now I noticed something: `$(form).find(".input input").each(function() { console.log($(this)); });` still returns the whole form, and not the individual objects, but only when loaded through AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a pesky bug to find, but I ultimately found it.
A few minutes earlier I had found out that `$(form).find(".input input").each(function() { console.log($(this)); });` was logging whole Form elements and not input elements as expected.

Then I figured the bug out, the new code for `setContent(html, url)` is:

```
function setContent(html, url) {
    html = $.parseHTML(html);
    $(".middle .container .text").html(html);
    $(html).filter("form").each(function() {
        preprocess($(this));
    });
    setNavTitle(url);
    //only if you actually load a different page
    if (currentFilename() != url) {
        window.history.pushState({
            "url": url
        }, "", url);
    }
}
```

Note that I added **`html = $.parseHTML(html);`**. This is **really** neccessary if you want to use jQuery properly on (incomplete) HTML.

Answer (score 1):

What seems to me is this your:

```
var checkField
```

variable is alreay an jQuery object so you don't have a need to wrap it again to make a jquery object. so instead you have to apply this way:

```
            checkField.css("color", "#FFFF00");
            checkField.html("&#x2718;");
            errorField.css("color", "#FFFF00");
            errorField.html("(Required)");
```

Try changing this way and see if this helps.

Comment: It doesn't help to fix my issues indeed. One of the only reasons I am using `$()` around it is actually such that NetBeans recognizes the jQuery functions on it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're adding the returned html to the page then trying to process the html string instead of the new elements created in the page:

Try changing this:

```
$(".middle .container .text").html(html);
$(html).filter("form").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    preprocess($(this));
});
```

To this:

```
$(".middle .container .text").html(html).filter("form").each(function() {
    console.log($(this));
    preprocess($(this));
});
```